# How to disable Tor-Browser updates through source code

Tags: updates, tor, recompile

I know that i can disable Tors update through browser; -> Options->  Advanced->Update -> Tor Browser update.
but, is there a way to cancel those updates through Tor source code by changing the `main` file or any other file and re-compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add those lines:

> user_pref("app.update.auto", false);
>
> user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);

to `prefs.js` file before you run Tor-Browser

Comment: i can't find this file before i run Tor- which means that i must run Tor to see this file. after i run Tor i can can change the file but  its not doing nothing. maybe you have another way to disable the updates?

Comment: put these lines in the new file `user.js` in the profile directory.